# unable to uninstall from eclipse marketplace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I've got a problem regarding the eclipse-marketplace (Juno):

I've installed the **Android Configurator for M2E** via marketplace.

Eclipse resolved following dependencies:

- Android Configurator for M2E
- Android Development Tools
- m2e

Everything was fine until I decided to uninstall it again.

Eclipse told me:

> "m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse" cannot be fully uninstalled because other installed >software requires it.  The parts that are not required will be uninstalled.

I confirmed and uninstalled the two other Android related modules.

Unfortunately my marketplace is in a weird state now:
When I try to reinstall **Android Configurator for M2E**, eclipse pretends that it's still installed and only offers me the option to uninstall it again.

I'm stuck in an infinity loop, please help :-)

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Help > About > Installed Software.
2. Fully expand all the nodes
3. Check for which nodes also list m2e as a dependency

You should be able to see which top-level feature is also requiring m2e to be installed.  It could be that your top level product (if you are using the Eclipse For Java Developers) is requiring m2e and you can't simply uninstall it.

Comment: I solved the problem for me by reinstalling the connector.

Can anyone confirm that applications installed from the marketplace are still shown as **installed** after unstallation, if a dependency could not be removed?

Comment: How did you reinstall the connector? I'm now having the same issue that after uninstalling the connector I cannot install it anymore (Only shows me the "Uninstall" button, which fails)

Comment: I did not manage to reinstall the connector using the Marketplace.

However you can still manually reinstall it:

**Help** -> **Install New Software**.

The update site is: http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/updates/